# Material UI: Responsive font size

Tags: javascript, material-ui

In Tailwind, this is how I would change the font size responsively:

```
<div className="text-xl sm:text-4xl">Hello World</div>
```

In Material UI, it is using Typography and how can the text size be changed responsively? For example, use h3 on sm and above.

```
<Typography variant="h1" component="h1">
  Hello World
</Typography>
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the media query and breakpoints provided by the Material UI to set the desired font size w.r.t screen size.

More info here: [Material UI - Responsive Fonts](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes)